# sql: delete a subtree table(id, Parentid) , delete a item with all his children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
foo(id, parentId) 
-- there is a FK constraint from parentId to id
```

and I need to delete an item with all his children and children of the children etc.
anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, `SQL SERVER` doesn't like cascade deletes for hierarchal relationships. So you could do both CTE (as [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787032/sql-delete-a-subtree-tableid-parentid-delete-a-item-with-all-his-children/2787082#2787082) mentioned) or a solution with a recursive trigger (somehow like [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=59240)). But I suppose, CTE is easier.

See, here is solution using CTE:

```
CREATE PROC deleteFoo 
@id bigint
as
WITH Nodes ([Id], [ParentId], [Level]) 
AS (
    SELECT  F.[Id], F.[ParentId], 0 AS [Level]
    FROM    [dbo].Foo F
    WHERE   F.[Id] = @id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  F.[Id], F.[ParentId], N.[Level] + 1
    FROM    [dbo].Foo F
        INNER JOIN Nodes N ON N.[Id] = F.[ParentId]
)

DELETE
FROM    Foo
WHERE   [Id] IN (
    SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT N.[Id] 
    FROM    Nodes N
    ORDER BY N.[Level] DESC
)
```

firstly, we're defining recursive CTE, and then deleting records from the `[Foo]` table beginning from the very child records (hightest `Level`; so, the top node will be deleted in the last turn).

Comment: what's with the top 100 percent thing ? is it going to delete only first 100 rows ?

Comment: @Omu, nope. `TOP 100 PERCENT` mean all the records. Without it you'll get `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.` error. So this is a workaround only.

Comment: I believe the order by in the subquery is redundant. Same will be achieved with (SELECT N.[Id] FROM Nodes N). I don't think there is a concept of deleting the top level last. All rows are deleted simultaneously and even if they were not you are ordering only the argument of the IN clause and not the DELETE. My test did not result in FK violation when changing the sort order to ASC so I believe it confirms that the inner select is redundant.

Comment: Agree, `ORDER BY` is redundant in `DELETE` statements unless not in a cursor with some fancy logic directly depending on the order of the items to be deleted. But looks nice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx), the anchor would be the initial Id.